# A child container failed during start SpringBoot project converted into Jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I come back again with one of my problem.

I have developped a SpringBoot app but I have now some errors. When I launch the app with Eclipse I don't have any error. But when I convert it in a runnable jar file and I lauch it I have these errors : I don't understand why is it working with eclipse and not in a jar file.

```
:: Spring Boot ::(v2.6.7)

2022-05-19 08:05:29.366  INFO 5520 --- [main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication: Starting DemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_333 on machinetest with PID 5520 (started by tdriss in C:\Users\tdriss\Desktop\Documents)
2022-05-19 08:05:29.378  INFO 5520 --- [main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-05-19 08:06:00.841  INFO 5520 --- [main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-05-19 08:06:01.501  INFO 5520 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-05-19 08:06:01.501  INFO 5520 --- [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.62]
2022-05-19 08:06:01.811 ERROR 5520 --- [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@14d81f2c]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_333]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) [jar:rsrc:spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:22) [rsrc:./:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61) [OPAL2022tomcatenable.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@14d81f2c]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4885) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5023) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined
        at java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.<init>(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:130) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.getInstanceInternal(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:53) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:77) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.registerURLStreamHandlerFactory(StandardRoot.java:711) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:698) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        ... 44 common frames omitted

2022-05-19 08:06:01.820 ERROR 5520 --- [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) [jar:rsrc:spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:22) [rsrc:./:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61) [OPAL2022tomcatenable.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@14d81f2c]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@14d81f2c]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4885) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5023) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined
        at java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.<init>(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:130) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.getInstanceInternal(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:53) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:77) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.registerURLStreamHandlerFactory(StandardRoot.java:711) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:698) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136) [jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        ... 44 common frames omitted

2022-05-19 08:06:01.830  INFO 5520 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-05-19 08:06:03.335  WARN 5520 --- [main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2022-05-19 08:06:03.363  INFO 5520 --- [main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-05-19 08:06:03.428 ERROR 5520 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[jar:rsrc:spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:22) [rsrc:./:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61) [OPAL2022tomcatenable.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) ~[jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[jar:rsrc:spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:na]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@14d81f2c]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@14d81f2c]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4885) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5023) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined
        at java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.<init>(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:130) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.getInstanceInternal(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:53) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:77)~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.registerURLStreamHandlerFactory(StandardRoot.java:711)~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:698) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136) ~[jar:rsrc:tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:na]
        ... 44 common frames omitted
```

I have already try to resolve this by adding

```
TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.disable();
```

The problem is solved with that but when I want to make an api request on localhost:8080 in my browser, I have this in the console

```
2022-05-19 09:29:03.166  INFO 972 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-05-19 09:29:03.195  INFO 972 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-05-19 09:29:03.212  INFO 972 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 13 ms
```

And I have a 404 Error in my browser, I precise that I don't have this problem with the project on eclipse.

And this is my POM file

https://codebeautify.org/alleditor/y2226566c

Comment: sharing more info e.g. the POM might help...

Comment: Yes I wanted to add it but I didn't have enough characters available. I will add it.

Comment: This is my POM.xml https://codebeautify.org/alleditor/y2226566c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when launching a jar application of SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72285458/error-when-launching-a-jar-application-of-springboot) - you've already asked this question yesterday, and it was closed as duplicate. Instead of asking it again - edit your exiting one and explain why it isn't a duplicate if the original solution didn't help you. Please take the [tour], and see [ask]

Comment: I mean, you are missing the key info here. Since you said "The problem is solved", I assumed you started the server successfully. And if it is issue with calling the API, no one would be able to help without knowing what code you have written. Also, get rid of the things which are irrelevant...

Comment: @OlafKock I put this as duplicate and resolved because I though that it was resolved but in fact no.  I had some other problems that's why I opened a new subject because this subject has a different error compared to the older one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was just linked with the version of Java and the Java library version. There was also a problem with the export in jar, it was necessary to choose copy required libraries into a sub folder and not the two other options, when we makethe runnable jar file export.